# How can I give the option of repeating the input for a switch statement in C++

Tags: c++

Hi I'm playing around with basic looping techniques and I'm trying to make the following code work. When the user inputs a number other than those allowed it will go to the default where I want to give them the option to try again (without just subbing the whole code into the default) or to just exit.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int input;
    char ans;
    cout<<"Hi please pick 1, 2 or 3: ";
    cin>> input;

    switch(input){
    case 1:
        cout<<"\nYou picked one\n";
        break;
    case 2:
        cout<<"\nYou picked two\n";
        break;
    case 3:
        cout<<"\nYou picked three\n";
        break;
    default:
        cout<<"\nYou didn't pick a valid option.\nWould you like to try again?(y/n)";
        cin>>ans;
        if(ans== 'y'){
            break;
        }else{
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this I get the error that continue isn't in any loop. I'm not really quite sure how to use the continue statement. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So.... add a loop. Google `while` loops. And read a C++ book.

Comment: @Cyber +1. Additionally, it's a good idea to accompany such comments with a link to [the list of good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Sometimes I wish goto wasn't so chastised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue:

`continue` statement:

> Causes the remaining portion of the enclosing for, range-for, while or do-while loop body skipped.
>   Used when it is otherwise awkward to ignore the remaining portion of the loop using conditional statements.

You need to put the core of your function in a `for` loop or `while` loop.

```
bool stop = false;
while ( !stop )
{
   cout<<"Hi please pick 1, 2 or 3: ";
   cin>> input;

   stop = true;
   switch(input){
      case 1:
         cout<<"\nYou picked one\n";
         break;
      case 2:
         cout<<"\nYou picked two\n";
         break;
      case 3:
         cout<<"\nYou picked three\n";
         break;
      default:
         cout<<"\nYou didn't pick a valid option.\nWould you like to try again?(y/n)";
         cin>>ans;
         if(ans== 'y'){
            stop = false;
         }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your `switch` statement inside a loop (`while(1)`) or (`for(;;)`), then it will work.